# Hiding Buttons on Safari Browser - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function below to hide buttons on my safari browser but I notice the button is only hidden on desktop browser and not phone browser. Is the mobile not able to read typeof safari?  How possible can I get this resolved?

file.js

```
if(typeof safari !== 'undefined')
{
    document.getElementId('btn').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check is safari

```
let is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
```

work flow

```
let browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 

if (browser.indexOf('safari')){
   document.getElementId('btn').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: How is this different ? Can you add some explanation